# Optimization for the solution of farmer goat wolf and cabbage problem in Prolog

Tags: prolog, river-crossing-puzzle

I am searching for a **better** algorithm , more  computational efficient, for the classical "**wolf, goat and cabbage**" problem, in **Prolog**. The algorithm below is based on BFS search for possible situations.

The **Problem**:

"Once upon a time a farmer went to a market and purchased a wolf, a goat, and a cabbage. On his way home, the farmer came to the bank of a river and rented a boat. But crossing the river by boat, the farmer could carry only himself and a single one of his purchases: the wolf, the goat, or the cabbage.

If left unattended together, the wolf would eat the goat, or the goat would eat the cabbage.

The farmer's challenge was to carry himself and his purchases to the far bank of the river, leaving each purchase intact. How did he do it?"

A **current** solution for this problem is this one:

````
writelist([H|T]):-
       write(H), writelist(T).

empty_stack([]).
stack(Top, Stack, [Top|Stack]).
member_stack(Element, Stack):-
       member(Element, Stack).


reverse_print_stack(S):-
               empty_stack(S).
reverse_print_stack(S):-
               stack(E, Rest, S),
               reverse_print_stack(Rest),
               write(E), nl.


unsafe(state(X,Y,Y,C)):-
       opp(X, Y).
unsafe(state(X,W,Y,Y)):-
       opp(X, Y).

move(state(X,X,G,C), state(Y,Y,G,C)):-
       opp(X,Y), not(unsafe(state(Y,Y,G,C))),
       writelist(['try farmer takes wolf ',Y,Y,G,C]),nl.

move(state(X,W,X,C), state(Y,W,Y,C)):-
       opp(X,Y), not(unsafe(state(Y,W,Y,C))),
       writelist(['try farmer takes goat ',Y,W,Y,C]),nl.

move(state(X,W,G,X), state(Y,W,G,Y)):-
       opp(X,Y), not(unsafe(state(Y,W,G,Y))),
       writelist(['try farmer takes cabbage ',Y,W,G,Y]),nl.

move(state(X,W,G,C), state(Y,W,G,C)):-
       opp(X,Y), not(unsafe(state(Y,W,G,C))),
       writelist(['try farmer takes self ',Y,W,G,C]),nl.

move(state(F,W,G,C), state(F,W,G,C)):-
       writelist([' BACKTRACK from: ',F,W,G,C]),nl,fail.

path(Goal, Goal, Been_stack):-
       nl, write('Solution Path is: '), nl,
       reverse_print_stack(Been_stack).


path(State, Goal, Been_stack):-
       move(State, Next_state),
       not(member_stack(Next_state, Been_stack)),
       stack(Next_state, Been_stack, New_been_stack),
       path(Next_state, Goal, New_been_stack),!.


opp(e,w).
opp(w,e).


go(Start, Goal):-
       empty_stack(Empty_been_stack),
       stack(Start, Empty_been_stack, Been_stack),
       path(Start, Goal, Been_stack).


test:-go(state(w,w,w,w), state(e,e,e,e)). ```
````

Comment: Currently going through the above (it can be simplified considerably ... there is no need to have the helper predicates to extend a list as Prolog programmers recognize list extension for what it is) but here is a problem: "path(Next_state, Goal, New_been_stack),!." ... why the cut? You want to search, it makes no sense to "commit" to the path currently chosen, which is, after all, just a first guess, a stab in the dark. Don't cut here! Plus, the above is resolutely Depth-First-Search, not Breadth-First (in which case, irterative deepening is recommended to avoid the tar pit of memory usage)

Comment: The move generator which generates the same state, then prints "BACKTRACK FROM" also makes scant sense. (Ok, it is meant to print out the fact that safe move generation failed, as a catchall) The "backtracking" occurs in path/3 though

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaned-up / simplified version (IMHO).

Overall, there is not much to be optimized.

It's standard Depth-First Search for a path through a state space.

For Breadth-First Search, another approach is needed.

One *could* try to make lookup of visited states faster than linear scanning (i.e. some kind of hashtable), but for a history of length 8 that's really not worth it.

```
% The state indicates the position of: Farmer, Wolf, Goat, Cabbage
% which is always one of east ('e') or west ('w').

unsafe(state(e,w,w,_)).  % Wolf and Goat are on the same border and the farmer ain't there
unsafe(state(w,e,e,_)).  % Wolf and Goat are on the same border and the farmer ain't there

unsafe(state(e,_,w,w)).  % Goat and Cabbage are on the same border and the farmer ain't there
unsafe(state(w,_,e,e)).  % Goat and Cabbage are on the same border and the farmer ain't there

opp(e,w).
opp(w,e).
       
% Valid next state generation

move(state(X,X,G,C), state(Y,Y,G,C)):-
   opp(X,Y), 
   \+ unsafe(state(Y,Y,G,C)),
   format("try farmer takes wolf ~q -> ~q\n",[state(X,X,G,C), state(Y,Y,G,C)]).

move(state(X,W,X,C), state(Y,W,Y,C)):-
   opp(X,Y),
   \+ unsafe(state(Y,W,Y,C)),
   format("try farmer takes goat ~q -> ~q\n",[state(X,W,X,C), state(Y,W,Y,C)]).

move(state(X,W,G,X), state(Y,W,G,Y)):-
   opp(X,Y),
   \+ unsafe(state(Y,W,G,Y)),   
   format("try farmer takes cabbage ~q -> ~q\n",[state(X,W,G,X), state(Y,W,G,Y)]).
   
move(state(X,W,G,C), state(Y,W,G,C)):-
   opp(X,Y),
   \+ unsafe(state(Y,W,G,C)),
   format("try farmer takes self ~q -> ~q\n",[state(X,W,G,C), state(Y,W,G,C)]).

not_yet_seen(State,History) :-                       % will fail if  member(State, History) 
   member(State, History),
   !,
   format("State ~q already seen\n",[State]),
   fail.

not_yet_seen(_,_).                                   % the replacement: success if \+ member(State, History)
   
path(State, State, History) :-                       % found a solution! (but maybe not the BEST solution)
   !,                                                % don't continue the search down this history
   reverse(History,RevHistory),
   maplist(term_to_atom,RevHistory,RevHistoryAtoms),
   atomic_list_concat(RevHistoryAtoms, '->', OutputAtom),
   length(History,L),
   format("A solution of length ~d: ~q\n",[L,OutputAtom]).

path(CurState, FinalState, History) :-
   move(CurState, NextState),                        % generate a safe next state
   not_yet_seen(NextState, History),                 % that hasn't been seen yet
   (true;(format("Backtracking from using ~q\n",[NextState]),fail)),
   path(NextState, FinalState, [NextState|History]). % add it to the visited states and recurse

go(StartState, FinalState) :- 
   path(StartState, FinalState, [StartState]). % 3rd arg is "history"

test :- 
   go(state(w,w,w,w),  % first everything is west 
      state(e,e,e,e)). % then everything is east
```

It finds two solutions of history length 8:

```
?- test.
try farmer takes goat state(w,w,w,w) -> state(e,w,e,w)
try farmer takes goat state(e,w,e,w) -> state(w,w,w,w)
State state(w,w,w,w) already seen
try farmer takes self state(e,w,e,w) -> state(w,w,e,w)
try farmer takes wolf state(w,w,e,w) -> state(e,e,e,w)
try farmer takes wolf state(e,e,e,w) -> state(w,w,e,w)
State state(w,w,e,w) already seen
try farmer takes goat state(e,e,e,w) -> state(w,e,w,w)
try farmer takes goat state(w,e,w,w) -> state(e,e,e,w)
State state(e,e,e,w) already seen
try farmer takes cabbage state(w,e,w,w) -> state(e,e,w,e)
try farmer takes wolf state(e,e,w,e) -> state(w,w,w,e)
try farmer takes wolf state(w,w,w,e) -> state(e,e,w,e)
State state(e,e,w,e) already seen
try farmer takes goat state(w,w,w,e) -> state(e,w,e,e)
try farmer takes goat state(e,w,e,e) -> state(w,w,w,e)
State state(w,w,w,e) already seen
try farmer takes cabbage state(e,w,e,e) -> state(w,w,e,w)
State state(w,w,e,w) already seen
Backtracking from using state(e,w,e,e)
Backtracking from using state(w,w,w,e)
try farmer takes cabbage state(e,e,w,e) -> state(w,e,w,w)
State state(w,e,w,w) already seen
try farmer takes self state(e,e,w,e) -> state(w,e,w,e)
try farmer takes goat state(w,e,w,e) -> state(e,e,e,e)
A solution of length 8: 'state(w,w,w,w)->state(e,w,e,w)->state(w,w,e,w)->state(e,e,e,w)->state(w,e,w,w)->state(e,e,w,e)->state(w,e,w,e)->state(e,e,e,e)'
true ;


Backtracking from using state(e,e,e,e)
try farmer takes self state(w,e,w,e) -> state(e,e,w,e)
State state(e,e,w,e) already seen
Backtracking from using state(w,e,w,e)
Backtracking from using state(e,e,w,e)
Backtracking from using state(w,e,w,w)
Backtracking from using state(e,e,e,w)
try farmer takes cabbage state(w,w,e,w) -> state(e,w,e,e)
try farmer takes goat state(e,w,e,e) -> state(w,w,w,e)
try farmer takes wolf state(w,w,w,e) -> state(e,e,w,e)
try farmer takes wolf state(e,e,w,e) -> state(w,w,w,e)
State state(w,w,w,e) already seen
try farmer takes cabbage state(e,e,w,e) -> state(w,e,w,w)
try farmer takes goat state(w,e,w,w) -> state(e,e,e,w)
try farmer takes wolf state(e,e,e,w) -> state(w,w,e,w)
State state(w,w,e,w) already seen
try farmer takes goat state(e,e,e,w) -> state(w,e,w,w)
State state(w,e,w,w) already seen
Backtracking from using state(e,e,e,w)
try farmer takes cabbage state(w,e,w,w) -> state(e,e,w,e)
State state(e,e,w,e) already seen
Backtracking from using state(w,e,w,w)
try farmer takes self state(e,e,w,e) -> state(w,e,w,e)
try farmer takes goat state(w,e,w,e) -> state(e,e,e,e)
A solution of length 8: 'state(w,w,w,w)->state(e,w,e,w)->state(w,w,e,w)->state(e,w,e,e)->state(w,w,w,e)->state(e,e,w,e)->state(w,e,w,e)->state(e,e,e,e)'
true ;


Backtracking from using state(e,e,e,e)
try farmer takes self state(w,e,w,e) -> state(e,e,w,e)
State state(e,e,w,e) already seen
Backtracking from using state(w,e,w,e)
Backtracking from using state(e,e,w,e)
try farmer takes goat state(w,w,w,e) -> state(e,w,e,e)
State state(e,w,e,e) already seen
Backtracking from using state(w,w,w,e)
try farmer takes cabbage state(e,w,e,e) -> state(w,w,e,w)
State state(w,w,e,w) already seen
Backtracking from using state(e,w,e,e)
try farmer takes self state(w,w,e,w) -> state(e,w,e,w)
State state(e,w,e,w) already seen
Backtracking from using state(w,w,e,w)
Backtracking from using state(e,w,e,w)
false.
```

Comment: I was searching for BFS optimization and for bigger history and also the best answer would be the smallest one.

Comment: The minimum length of the path and minimize the computational cost.